# Как программно добавить хранимую процедуру на MS SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server

Программа на C# WPF работает с базой данных на MS SQL Server с использованием SqlDataAdapter. При этом используются хранимые процедуры с параметрами для добавления данных в таблицу базы данных.

Возникла необходимость создания хранимой процедуры на SQL Server программным путем при развертывании базы данных. Однако, так как процедура содержит параметры при загрузке её на сервер возникают ошибки. Как исправить приведенный ниже код чтобы он корректно создавал хранимую процедуру на сервере?

```
const string CreateSPUnitsQuery = "if not exists (select * from sysobjects where name='sp_InsertUnit' and xtype='P') " +
                "CREATE PROCEDURE sp_InsertUnit " +
                "@Name nvarchar(40), " +
                "@Code int out AS " +
                "INSERT INTO Units (Name) " +
                "VALUES (@Name) " +
                "SET @Code = SCOPE_IDENTITY()";
try
{
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        conn.Open();
        if (conn.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandText = CreateSPUnitsQuery;
                cmd.ExecuteScalar();
            }
        }
        conn.Close();
    }
}
catch (Exception eSql)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Exception: " + eSql.Message + '\n');
    result = result + eSql.Message;
}
```

При этом возникают следующие ошибки:
Вызвано исключение: "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException" в System.Data.dll Exception: Неправильный синтаксис около ключевого слова "PROCEDURE". 
Необходимо объявить скалярную переменную "@Name". 
Необходимо объявить скалярную переменную "@Code".

Видно, что сервер пытается подставить в запрос значения переменных @Name и @Code,
что делать не нужно.
Попробовал обойти следующим образом. Вставил перед строкой cmd.ExecuteScalar(); следующее:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Code", SqlDbType.VarChar);
cmd.Parameters["@Code"].Value = "@Code";
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar);
cmd.Parameters["@Name"].Value = "@Name";
```

Все равно остается ошибка:
Вызвано исключение: "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException" в System.Data.dll
Exception: Неправильный синтаксис около ключевого слова "PROCEDURE".

И строка итогового текста запроса:
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE sp_InsertUnit @Name nvarchar(40), @Code int out AS INSERT INTO Units (Name) VALUES (@Name) SET @Code = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

Comment: "процедура содержит параметры ... возникают ошибки" - ??

Comment: Вызвано исключение: "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException" в System.Data.dll
Exception: Неправильный синтаксис около ключевого слова "PROCEDURE".
Необходимо объявить скалярную переменную "@Name".
Необходимо объявить скалярную переменную "@Code".

Comment: Заключите вставку в блок BEGIN... END

Comment: Так нельзя по синтаксису (T-SQL). Нельзя писать `IF ... CREATE PROCEDURE ...`, т.к. _Инструкцию CREATE PROCEDURE нельзя объединять с другими инструкциями Transact-SQL в одном пакете._ (см. [документацию](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/t-sql/statements/create-procedure-transact-sql), раздел _Ограничения_). Либо отдельными командами проверка и создание, либо без проверки `CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE` (доступно в версиях SqlServer начиная с 2016 SP1).

Comment: Ни заключение вставки в блок BEGIN … END, ни удаление условия IF … проблемы не решают. Ошибка: Неправильный синтаксис около ключевого слова "PROCEDURE". остается.

Comment: @АлексейШокарев добавьте в вопрос итоговый текст запроса который вам собирает шарп (можно с дебага).

Comment: Подскажите как посмотреть итоговый текст запроса?

Comment: В дебаге запустите, поставьте точку останова на шаг выполнения и покажите что вы тут cmd.CommandText = CreateSPUnitsQuery; положили

Comment: Добавил итоговую строку запроса в текст вопроса

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eсли версия MS SQL >=2016, то все должно быть ОК, если версия младше, для замены процедуры ее нужно обернуть:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (select * from sysobjects where name='sp_InsertUnit' and xtype='P')
EXEC('CREATE PROCEDURE sp_InsertUnit 
@Name nvarchar(40), 
@Code int out 
AS
BEGIN 
    INSERT INTO Units (Name) 
    VALUES (@Name);    
    SET @Code = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
END')
```

Comment: В таком варианте отлично работает. Спасибо! Хотя у меня и MS SQL 2017 без обертки не работало.